# Guardar datos en un array String

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, estoy empezando en la programacion con un bot Discord.
Quiero crear la caracteristica de que el usurio pueda elegir palabras baneadas de un canal.

cuando ingreso las palabras, el log muestra que el arreglo tiene las palabras usadas pero cuando alguien las utiliza, este arreglo es como si no existiera. Creo que es porque el arreglo esta declarado dentro de un evento (en este caso el msg.content.includes) que es donde le pido al usuario las palabras. No se como guardar en el arreglo estas palabras y que se queden guardadas.

```
if(command === "addbanwords"){
    let palabrasban = args;
    if (!palabrasban) return msg.channe.send("Agregue palabras para Banear");
    msg.channel.send('Las palabras: **${palabrasban}** fueron Baneadas');
    console.log(palabrastot)
    palabrastot.push(palabrasban);
```

El arreglo esta definido mas arriba como

```
var palabrastot
```

Comment: Esto es Java o Javascript? No es igual. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y usa la etiqueta correcta. Lo otro, el código en la pregunta no es un ejemplo mínimo verificable; es difícil que haya una respuesta correcta creada a partir de código inválido (quien intente responder va a adivinar)

Comment: Sin ver todo el código es difícil decir, pero si la variable se declara dentro de la función que llama a este if. con cada llamada se redefinirá y por eso estará vacía. Si la pones en un entorno mas global entonces verás los cambios en cada llamada. Aunque el contenido se borrará al reiniciar el servicio...